# ORA-01722: invalid number - value with two decimals

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr, ora-01722

I'm trying to get the max value from a text field.  All but two of the values are numbers with a single decimal.  However, two of the values have something like `8.2.10`.  How can I pull back just the integer value?  The values can go higher than `9.n`, so I need to convert this field into a number so that I can get the largest value returned.  So all I want to get back is the `8` from the `8.2.1`.

`Select cast(VERSION as int)` is bombing out because of those two values with a second `.` in them.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use T-SQL rather PL/SQL, but the idea is the same:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(10);
SELECT @s='8.2.1';
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@s, CHARINDEX('.', @s) - 1) AS INT);
```

returns the integer 8 - note that it won't work if there are no dots because it takes the part of the string to the left of the first dot.

If my quick look at equivalent functions was correct, then in Oracle that would end up as:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(VERSION, 1, INSTR(VERSION, '.') - 1) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle you must attend the value as string for retire only the part before the dot. Ex:

```
SELECT NVL( SUBSTR('8.2.1',0, INSTR('8.2.1','.')-1),'8.2.1') AS SR FROM DUAL;
```

Check than the value is repeated 3 times in the sentence, and if the value is zero or the value didn't have decimal part then it will return the value as was set.

Answer (score 0):

You may derive by using `regexp_substr` with `\d` pattern :

```
with tab as
(
 select regexp_substr('8.2.1', '\d', 1, 1) from dual
 union all
 select regexp_substr('9.0.1', '\d', 1, 1) from dual
)
select * from tab;
```